# Adding map markers from object using $.each doesn't work

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, each

Here is my code.  If I use loadGeoJson it shows the markers.  If I use $.getJSON to load the data to an object and step through it adding each marker, I don't see any markers.  I do see all the names show up in the "pList" div so I know it's looping properly and accessing the properties of the object properly.  What am I missing?

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
    participants = data.features;
}).done(function(){
    $.each( participants, function(i, p){
        $('#pList').append('<div>' + p.properties.name + '</div>');
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng (p.geometry.coordinates[0], p.geometry.coordinates[1]),
            map: map,
            title: p.properties.name
        });
    });
    //map.data.loadGeoJson('data.json');
});
```

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like?  Where is "map" defined?  Does it exist before the JSON data returns?

Comment: Sorry, the rest of the code is identical to the sample in the API.  Yes, map is previously declared.  I can post the full code on Monday if needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must switch the arguments for the marker-position.

In geoJSON the first item of a  Point-geometry is the longitude and the 2nd the latitude, but a `google.maps.LatLng` expects the order 1. latitude 2. longitude.

Currently your code will only draw a marker(but not at the desired location) when `p.geometry.coordinates[1]` is within the range `-85,85`, because that's the valid range for a latitude.

```
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng (p.geometry.coordinates[1],
                                          p.geometry.coordinates[0]),
        map: map,
        title: p.properties.name
    });
```

When this doesn't fix the problem the `map`-variable obviously isn't accessible inside the `done`-callback.

Comment: Nice catch on the coords, but how can I make map accessible in the callback?

Comment: It depends on the other code, currently you haven't posted where/how you create the map.

Comment: you run `$.getJSON` immediately(before `initialize`), when you got the result before `initialize` has been called, the `map` isn't created yet. Move the call of `$.getJSON` to the end of `initialize`